# CSS file in not being edit in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to edit css 
`"css_pF25-gpJPC5E_dzDNqsHs9AriR_AGzKkzgs-0VLNBgI.css"`
 when me put any my css in above file like `float:left` no effect appear in front-end and ,
Why the css file name is too complicated in drupal , what should I do ?
it is in drupal it contain in **"C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal_1\sites\default\files\css"**

Comment: Clear the cache maybe

Comment: CTRL + MAJ + R is your friend

Comment: where to press  
CTRL + MAJ + R

Comment: Seems you have CSS aggregation turned on. Devel module provides quick links in toolbar to clear caches (all, or just JS/CSS). Very handy.

Comment: I second what Flo says. You're trying to edit a file that is temporary by design. default/files/css is where drupal places processed css files. Go to `admin/config/development/performance` in your drupal site, and disable  `Aggregate and compress CSS files` Then your site will properly show all css resources as separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite confused how you got "css_pF25-gpJPC5E_dzDNqsHs9AriR_AGzKkzgs-0VLNBgI.css" in your DRUPAL file system.

Since its aggregated CSS file, you wont find any CSS file which has named like that. CSS aggregation is being done by DRUPAL end.

So best way of doing this is, got to following path: In admin menu,

Configuration >> Development >> Performance. In this page under "BANDWIDTH OPTIMIZATION" section, you see "Aggregate and compress CSS files" check box.

DE-select that check box and clear DRUPAL cache. And then inspect element which CSS your are going to change, there you see exact CSS file name which not is aggregated one.Go to that CSS file and make CSSchanges and save.

Then clear Drupal cache and you need to clear browser history also some times.

Then see changes on front end. If changes effected , go to
Configuration >> Development >> Performanace ,check "Aggregate and compress CSS files" check box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply create css file at "projectname/sites/all/themes/theme_name/css/abc.css". Write css code.

Clear cache from 
if using windows then

"Home » Administration » Configuration » Development » Performance" this path and press clear all cache button.

if using linux
go to the project path for example "/var/www/project_name/" and hit drush cc all it will clear all cache. and changes will be reflect.

Note: You should installed drush module.

Actually drupal merges all css and create a css file with dynamic name.

Hpe it will help you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Stop, why you CSS file named "css_pF25-gpJPC5E_dzDNqsHs9AriR_AGzKkzgs-0VLNBgI.css"? Create normal style.css file, put on **theme_floder/css/** and include style in **theme.info** file. But i don't understend you question?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit a temporary file generated by Drupal's cache. Edit your actual CSS file (you can find this in the .info file of your theme) and then clear the cache: /admin/config/development/performance